# Gnuplot math bold symbols

Tags: label, gnuplot

I would like to set bold labels in my graph. I use the latex enviroment to set formula at the labels between `$` symbols, hovwer the usual `\boldsymbol{}` doesn't work.

```
set terminal epslatex standalone color size 4.0in,3.0in background rgb "white" font "Helvetica,10"

set output 'latex.tex'

f(x) = x + 2*sin(x)
set xrange [0:10]

set xlabel '$t$'
set ylabel '$\boldsymbol{q} \cdot n$'
plot f(x)
```

Comment: How looks the line with `boldsymbol` in the output of your tex file? Maybe you need `\\\`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't compile and the terminal gives me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add to your latex file:

`\usepackage{amsmath}`

You can do this from gnuplot by using the `header` option of `epslatex`:

`set terminal epslatex standalone color size 4.0in,3.0in background rgb "white" font "Helvetica,10" header '\usepackage{amsmath}'`